# ChromeDriver - Cannot launch driver on Mac os x in Xamarin

Tags: c#, macos, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hy, I've tried to run some selenium tests that are written in Xamarin, in c# on Mac OS X, but chrome driver cannot be launched. This error appears:
 "OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException chromedriver.exe does not exist".

I found different solutions for java, by settings the property to the driver, but not for C#

Thank you,
Raluca